# ios - THEOS linking error for default tweak

Tags: ios, theos

I am starting to develop tweaks from my macbook pro and I and getting the following compiler / linker error when I do `make package`:

```
> Making all for tweak CorrectVolume…
==> Compiling Tweak.x (arm64)…
==> Linking tweak CorrectVolume (arm64)…
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libc++.dylib, building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
ld: in '/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib', building for iOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [/Users/joseperezcano/Desktop/Objective_C/correctvolume/.theos/obj/debug/arm64/CorrectVolume.dylib] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/Users/joseperezcano/Desktop/Objective_C/correctvolume/.theos/obj/debug/arm64/CorrectVolume.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [CorrectVolume.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

The program is the one generated by `nic.pl` without anything else, the tweak isn't supposed to do anything and even so it doesn't compiles. However, when I try to compile from my iPhone it compiles perfectly. I've tried reinstalling the llvm but it didn't change the result.

In case this information is relevant, I have all the sdk patched from the theos github plus one more for iOS 13.4.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by updating my OS to Monterey. Then I run brew doctor to make sure everything was running smoothly and reinstalled theos. After that everything is compiling correctly.